AWS sam local start-api with aws integration type calls lambdas with aws_proxy events
I have been testing sam local start-api with a AWS::Serverless::Api defined by OpenApi 3.0.2 spec.
I integrated lambda function via aws integration type but when I call the mocked gateway, I am getting aws-proxy lambda event.
I cannot find any reference that aws integration is not supported. Is this some misconfiguration or is this integration type officially supported?
